# Move VMDK files to different datacenter

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, migration, datacenter, veeam

I am looking for a possible methods to migrate VMs from vSphere 4.1 to new vSphere 4.1.
What is the best way to do this minimal downtime? 
I want to know how to migrate an virtualized active directory server 2003 and exchange server 2007 to a new VMWare Server.
I want to know the tools, procedures, best practice...
the moral of the story how can i migrate VMs from different physical data centre to one data center?
I'm asking as an alternative solution. I have Veeam Backup & Replication 6.5.0.109 is it possible 
the replication possible from different physical data centre to one data center?if so how can I do that?

BTW We do no have shared storage. The old vSphere 4.1 has  directly attached external hard drive. 
I do not have licensed for Storage vMotion.

Options:- with some downtime....

1. Backup and Restore using your existing Backup and Restore software.
2. Export and Import using vSphere Client
3. Veeam Backup & Replication :replicate all VMs over WAN link to new datacenter

What do you recommended above options?

Comment: Export as a vAPP?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by "Export as a vAPP" ? please clarify.

Comment: This site is for professionals, who know the basics of what they're trying to do - you're clearly not trained in what you're asking nor have the basic research skills to have understood what I was suggesting. Perhaps this site isn't for you.

Comment: @Chopper3 Perhaps then you should vote to close? Be consequent.

Comment: @TomTom - sorry, I thought I had, have now

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the downvotes as I think it is legit question for somebody who is using free version of vmware and doesn't understand vAPPs.

Moving on to the question, lets talk about your 3 ideas:

*Backup and Restore using your existing Backup and Restore software.* - This will only work if your existing backup software can handle bare metal recoevery, for OS that is.

*Export and Import using vSphere Client* - This is a good option and should work well.

*Veeam Backup & Replication :replicate all VMs over WAN link to new datacenter* - Not sure as I have never tried Veeam backup myself before.

Comment: The downvotes are because "does not understand his technology" is not compatible with "must show minimal understanding of the technology" as per FAQ. At least most likely.

Comment: @TomTom I understand that part, but can I respectfully disagree that vApp answer might not apply in this situation? For free version of vmware  there is no option to use vAPP(atleast in v4). So why should end user understand what vApp is? He already suggested 3 options which means he has an idea of what works and was just asking for clarification. I know mods have a tough job of keeping the site relevant, but do the enduser has to really learn that much just to ask a question?

Answer (score 0):

Use robocoy.. (making a few assumptions)

```
rem ## source
net use \\source\share /user:domain1\administrator Password

rem ## copy data 
robocopy \\source\share \\destination\share /s /copy:dat /dcopy:t /xo /r:0 /w:0 /log+:robocopy.log

rem ## disconnect
net use \\source\share /d
```